# How to remove a file from being tracked by git?

Tags: git, github

I have a file **config-dev.php** which will be used as a dev version config.

Now, another developer wants to make his own changes in this file.

When he commits, this file is commited and my config-dev.php is overwritten by the file from my coworker.

this file is in **.gitignore** but it is still not working.

How do I remove this file from git index so everyone can have its own config-dev.php?

I tried `git rm --cached config-dev.php` but it is still not working. Should this command be executed by all the coworkers? or should I sync after git rm??

Comment: That's odd. Did you `commit` and `push` after doing the `git rm`? Also, this is a duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore) though there it's not stated explicitly that you need to `commit` and `push` the change.

Comment: Also relevant: [Stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/q/936249/216074) and [What's the easiest way to deal with project configuration files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6782017/216074)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

1. remove the file from tracking:

   ```
   git rm --cached config-dev.php && git commit -m "config-dev.php"
   ```
2. add it to the `.gitignore`

   ```
   echo config-dev.php >> .gitignore
   git add .gitignore
   git commit -m "adding config-dev.php to .gitignore"
   ```
3. Publish these changes

   ```
   git push
   ```
4. On your colleagues machine fetch the new configuration

   ```
   git pull
   ```

Done

When your other dev gets errors on `pull` because of changes in her `config-dev.php`, she should copy her local changes away and then rename the file back after pushing:

```
cp config-dev.php my-config-dev.php
git checkout config-dev.php
git pull
mv my-config-dev.php config-dev.php
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to work! :)