# Git ignore already pushed file

Tags: git

I have a following problem: Basically, I have a Python project which uses a config file, so like `config.cfg` is present in the root of a project. I've already added, commited and pushed it to repo. And it is empty.

Users can read README to learn how to write one on their own, but I wanted to provide them with an empty one, so they don't have to create it, wonder about paths etc.

The problem is, when I write code/debug, I have this file filled with my own configuration data. And every time when I want to commit, I need to be careful, I cannot `git add .`, because it will add this modified `config.cfg`. I've added `config.cfg` to `.gitignore` of course, but it doesn't seem to help.

Is it possible to `.gitignore` already tracked, commited and pushed file, or do I have to always like manually not stage it?

Comment: add a `config.local.cfg`, add it to `.gitignore` and make that the default one being read for development?

Comment: Thank you, @Quentin, that was it!

Comment: @Quentin See my better answer below ;)

Comment: @Philippe interesting, TIL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/how-to-stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ignore+tracked+file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782017/whats-the-easiest-way-to-deal-with-project-configuration-files

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+application+configuration+files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `git update-index --skip-worktree`.

A lot of people say to use `--assume-unchanged` which has a very similar behavior but should be reserved for performance problems on big files.

`skip-worktree` is intended for files changed by the developer.

So, do:

`git update-index --skip-worktree config.cfg`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/717372 for more details