# GIT: How to add file to repo but ignore it for changes

Tags: git, github

I have a file with app configuration. I want to add this file to the repo so everyone could have basic configuration but ignore any changes in file if someone will want to modify configuration.

I know about `assume-unchanged` but it looks like it is only for local repo, when somebody will clone the repo and change this file git will mark it as modified.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the easiest way to deal with project configuration files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782017/whats-the-easiest-way-to-deal-with-project-configuration-files)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+application+config+file

Comment: No, I need specially what is written in the question about git

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear what is asked for.

Comment: I want to have file in repo (including remote) which locally don't track changes

Answer (score 0):

Even if there is a technical solution to the problem, I don't think you should seek it. As a user of your repository, if I kept changing this one file and it wasn't showing up in my stage, I'd be very confused.

Mark the file as do not edit, either in a comment in the file, or in the readme if the file does not allow comments.

Then, if someone wants to make modifications to it and sees it in stage, it's their responsibility to set an ignore on the file.

Comment: There is an agreement, so there will be no confusion when you change file and there are no modified state in git

Comment: Another solution is also to not have the file in git, add its name to gitignore, and create a script that generates the file, e.g. in Makefile, or a simple shell/bat script. That way, you can tell people to generate the file, yet their changes won't show up in stage.

Comment: Maybe it is good as workaround, but perfect solution will be is to ignore modifictions

Comment: Or add a pre-commit hook that prevents commits if that file is modified.

Comment: Typically though, it's the user's responsibility to set which files to ignore. It seems like a smell to enforce it.

Answer (score 0):

- Call your configuration `config-template.conf` and provide that through the repo.
- In the README, instruct users to rename the template to `config.conf` which your application expects to find.
- Add `config.conf` to your `.gitignore`.

The `config.conf` will not be tracked.

Comment: I know about workarounds, but the question is about GIT

Comment: @aspirisen This *is* using git. Maybe you can clarify in your question what specifically an answer must use?