# IIS php powershell with user switch

Tags: php, windows, powershell, iis

I have an IIS with php 5.6.

I am writing a PHP script, which should execute a powershell script.

The powershell script has to switch to another user because the IUSR user does not have the privileges for the needed commands in the powershell.

Source:

**PHP call of powershell:**

```
$content = shell_exec("powershell.exe  -NonInteractive -command " . getcwd() . "\\ps-helper.ps1 -ps_password '".$powershell_password."' < NUL");
```

As it is  (to my knowledge) not possible to switch user within a script, I split them up in two files. the ps-helper.ps1 should start the second script with different credentials:

**ps-helper.ps1:**

```
$psuser_secpassword  = ConvertTo-SecureString $ps_password -AsPlainText -Force
$psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$psi.CreateNoWindow = $true
$psi.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$psi.Arguments = "/?"
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false;
$psi.RedirectStandardInput = $true;
$psi.RedirectStandardError = $true;
$psi.RedirectStandardOutput = $True;
$psi.Username = 'username'
$psi.Domain = 'DOMAIN'
$psi.Password = $psuser_secpassword
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $psi
$p.Start()
$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
$p.WaitForExit()
```

If I execute the command via cmd.exe in windows as normal user, it works fine.

**Problem:**

- If I execute the command via IIS it fails, no reason given (stdout and stderr are empty)
- If I comment out Username, Domain and Password, it works - meaning $stdout is filled with output from second script (but obviously no user change)

Are there any settings in Windows, IIS, PHP or powershell that prevent user change from IUSR to something else?

Comment: It's an IIS security feature as far as I'm aware. It won't allow code to impersonate / logon as a different user. It's possible to bypass it by getting a logon token and passing that to a Process object. But have you considered running the app pool as a different user that already has permission to run the script?

Comment: @arco444 good hint, do you have a sample for login token usage? I would prefer to not change the IUSR if possible. But if I can't find any other solution, it can't be avoided but change the app pool user.

Comment: Another option might be to create a constained, delegated session on the server using delegated credentials that have permission to run the command, and giving the IUSR account permssion to use the session.  Then write your script to use Invoke-Command, pointed at that session.

Comment: @Kaffee [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661170/asp-net-application-executing-powershell-scripts-as-iis-usr) is related and although unaccepted, the links in the comments will give you an idea of what is required for the token approach