# Get-WmiObject credentials not working when scheduled

Tags: powershell, windows-xp

I have a Powershell script to detect disk space on a network server that requires a user/password to access it.

I followed this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/440ab7ed-7727-4ff7-a34a-6e69e2dff251/

To get this code:

```
$password = get-content C:\creds.txt | convertto-securestring
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "username",$password
Get-WmiObject -ErrorAction Stop Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $deviceName -credential $cred -Filter "DeviceID='$darg'"
```

`$deviceName` and `$darg` are already correctly defined.

This works just fine when running the Powershell script manually. But when I set it up as a Windows schedule task, it fails thinking the user/pass is incorrect:

> Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESS
>   DENIED))
>
> $disks = Get-WmiObject <<<<  -ErrorAction Stop Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $deviceName -credential $cred -Filter
>   "DeviceID='$darg'"
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WmiObject], Unauthorized AccessException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

Why is this? (The account is a local user on the remote server. I've tried entering the credentials on the Schedule interface but it doesn't let me save it, saying invalid login; maybe due to being a local account) `ServerName\LocalUser` does not work in the Windows Schedule UI, still gives the incorrect login error.

Comment: Try using ServerName\LocalUser as the username. Consider that the specified account must be a user of the local administrators group on the target server.

Comment: I am under the impression that convertto/from-securestring works on a per-user basis if you don't provide a specific key value. IOW, one user can't read another user's data. This pre-existing SO question seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109958/saving-credentials-for-reuse-by-powershell-and-error-convertto-securestring-ke. There is also relevant information discussion at Powershellcommunity.org: http://powershellcommunity.org/Forums/tabid/54/aft/8122/Default.aspx

Comment: @darinstrait That was it, thanks. Feel free to drop that as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my comment, re-worded as an answer.

The convertto/from-securestring functions work on a per-user basis (if you don't provide a specific key value). IOW, one user can't read another user's data.

[This pre-existing SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109958/saving-credentials-for-reuse-by-powershell-and-error-convertto-securestring-ke) seems relevant. [There is also relevant discussion](http://powershellcommunity.org/Forums/tabid/54/aft/8122/Default.aspx) at Powershellcommunity.org.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you set the task to run under the user account and run the wmi request without credential ?

Comment: It's a local account on the remote server. I've tried it in the Scheduler UI, but it doesn't seem to recognize it's a valid login. Maybe because it's not on the domain.

Comment: need more info : when you say "This works just fine when running the Powershell script manually", the script run on the server ?

Comment: The script run on the same PC that it is scheduled on. So instead of running the schedule, I run the .ps1 file (the script) and it works fine.

Comment: So I maintain you should setup the task scheduler to run with your current credential. use computername\your_login as the username