# Secure String can't be decrypted after Sysprep

Tags: powershell, securestring, sysprep

I have two PowerShell scripts I'm building for a Windows 7 image.  Prior to the image I run `PRE-IMAGE.ps1`, and it has a line like this in it:

```
$JoinDomainPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the password for $joinDomainUser" -AsSecureString
$strPass = $joinDomainPassword | ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

I then save the the `$strPass` secure string to the registry, and run sysprep.

After a reboot with sysprep, the `POST-IMAGE.ps1` then pulls `$strPass` from the registry, and has a line like this:

```
$strPass = $strPass | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($JoinDomainUser, $strPass)
```

However, these lines in `POST-IMAGE.ps1` get the "Key not valid" error you'll see when you run `convertto-securestring` and `convertfrom-securestring` as different Windows users.  ([similiar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109958/saving-credentials-for-reuse-by-powershell-and-error-convertto-securestring-ke)) - but the catch here is I -AM- using the same user to convert to and from secure strings.  I'm guessing this has something to do with sysprep - but I can't wrap my head around it.

I apologize if this has been asked about before, I've found a few questions that touch on parts of this, but don't describe my EXACT problem.

Comment: Which user are you using, the built in Administrator user or a created user?

Comment: In the code example above, $joinDomainUser is a user on the domain who has permissions to add computer accounts.  

The script is being run as the local administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not specify a key for the ConvertFrom-SecureString command, it will use DPAPI to encrypt the string.  Sysprep apparently re-initializes the key used by DPAPI. From http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/security-crypto/t-local-machine-masterkey-in-dpapi-1053937-print.html

> DPAPI will generate the local system master key during the specialization phase of sysprep.

Comment: Thanks for the info Keith.  I'm wondering now, since DPAPI isn't available, what the best way to store the credentials is.  

I know I can use the "-key" parameter to convert the securestrings with something other than DPAPI, but now I'm trying to figure out what the best (most secure) way to store and use that key is.  Including it in the script is only slightly better than storing the password in clear text.

Comment: This won't help until V5 comes out (and maybe not even then) but have a look at this blog post http://bit.ly/CmsMessage.