# How do I execute a powershell script under a specified credential without a prompt?

Tags: powershell, vmware, credentials, microsoft-dynamics

I'm writing an 'Action Script' in VMWare AppDirector 'AppD' which installs MS Dynamics. (My action script is actually a powershell script). The way this works is that AppD will execute a powershell script on a newly deployed server, using a builtin administrator account. This script is one of the last steps in a highly orchestrated deployment. At this stage my SQL server has been deployed, the databases loaded, and I'm performing the final deployment.

When I run my script logged in as myself, everything works great. But of course that's executing under 'mydomain\myusername' which has access to the SQL server etc. However, when AppD executes this script under a local builtin account, it doesn't have the credentials needed by setup to authenticate against SQL, and make proper connections for install to succeed.

My first attempt was to just call a script, that invokes my actual deployment script, so I can pass credentials;

```
$user = "mydomain\myusername"
$pword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "mypassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $pword

Invoke-Command -FilePath "C:\Scripts\DeployAOS.ps1" -Credential $credential -Computer localhost
```

This looked like it might have worked, but when reviewing the install log I see the following error;

```
2015-03-09 13:15:19Z    Property DbSqlServer set to: 'SQLSERVER001'
2015-03-09 13:15:23Z    Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
```

My original DeployAOS.ps1 script contains this line, which kicks off the install;

```
# Perform AOS Installation
Start-Process -FilePath $exeAOSSetup -ArgumentList $cfgAOS -Wait
```

I have also tried just modifying my DeployAOS.ps1 to set the 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential' object w\ Username\Password, and doing something like this;

```
# Perform AOS Installation
Start-Process -FilePath $exeAOSSetup -ArgumentList $cfgAOS -Credential $credentials -Wait
```

And it really didn't like that. It feels like the AOS setup needs to be executed under a domain user, that has access to the SQL server, and maybe even have a user profile loaded while setup runs (So it can create a desktop shortcut, etc.)

Any ideas how I might go about solving this problem? I'm fairly new to scripting in powershell, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7109958/1377865) question